# Prove that a function is injective knowing the second derivative is positive

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives

I have this problem and I'm trying to figure out how to start:

> Suppose that $f$ has positive second derivative in $(a,b)$, then prove that $f$ is injective in $(a,b).$

I manage to show that $f'(x)$ is injective. Let $x_1,x_2\in(a,b),$ with $x_1≠x_2.$ By the mean value theorem, taking the interval $(x_1,x_2)$ exist $\xi\in(x_1,x_2)$ such that: 
$$\frac{f'(x_2)-f'(x_1)}{x_2-x_1}=f''(\xi);$$
$$f'(x_2)-f'(x_1)=(x_2-x_1) f''(\xi).$$
We have that $f''(\xi)\gt0$ by hypothesis and also $x_2-x_1\gt0,$ assuming that $x_2\gt x_1$ without losing generallity. So $f'(x_2)-f'(x_1)\gt0$ and that implies that $f'(x_1)≠f'(x_2).$
Anyone know how to proceed? Thanks.

Comment: not true. $x^2$ in $(-1,1)$.

Comment: Oh thanks, I did not think of looking for a counterexample. I understand now

Answer (score 0):

This is false. You can prove it is injective (even *increasing*) its *first* derivative is positive, or that it is *convex* if its second derivative is positive, but an easy counterexample to the posted claim can be found [above](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2841273/prove-that-a-function-is-injective-knowing-the-second-derivative-is-positive#comment5859251_2841273).

Answer (score 0):

If second derivative  of a function is positive on an interval, then the function is concave up but it does not have to be injective.

For example the function $$f(x)= x^2+1$$ on the interval $(-2,2)$ is not injective because $$f(1)=f(-1) = 2 $$ while its second derivative is $ f''(x) =2 >0$

Answer (score 0):

As they said is false. Also you can do a similar proof of this similar proposition: 
If $f'(x)≠0$ for all $x$, then $f$ is injective